# Can Cloudera Impala read any table in Hive?

Tags: impala

Does Cloudera Impala capable of reading **any** Hive table (i.e. Customer SerDer) ? I couldn't find any such statement in their official documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impala does not support custom Hive SerDes. From [What features from relational databases or Hive are not available in Impala?](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/Impala/Cloudera-Impala-Frequently-Asked-Questions/Cloudera-Impala-Frequently-Asked-Questions.html?scroll=faq_features_unique_1__faq_unsupported_unique_1) in the Impala documentation available from Cloudera:

> Custom Hive Serializer/Deserializer classes (SerDes). Impala supports
>   a set of common native file formats that have built-in SerDes in CDH.
>   See [How Impala Works with Hadoop File Formats](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/Impala/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_file_formats.html) for details.